# Rogue Ruby processes consuming all CPU. Ruby on Rails served by Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gdb, passenger

We are having problem with RoR application being served by Passenger on Apache. The app is fine when it starts up or when Apache is restarted but after a variable amount of time we start seeing ruby processes that are consuming all available CPU.

Sometimes these processes show in passenger-status and sometimes they don't. They always appear in top, taking up all the CPU.
These gradually build up and never get killed by Passenger.

I have attempted the following diagnostics:

### Strace:

Every time I run strace against them, their is no output coming out of them. If I attach strace to a healthy ruby process from passenger-status then I can see information being logged about what that process is doing. Here is output from rogue process:

```
strace -f -p 8648
Process 8648 attached with 2 threads - interrupt to quit
[pid  8650] select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, NULL

I'll then go into top and the thread is sigging at 88%. When I o back to strace.. there is nothing. Just the following output:
strace -c -p 8648
Process 8648 attached - interrupt to quit
^CProcess 8648 detached
```

### gdb:

I ran the following commands against one of these rogue processes:

```
sudo gdb
attach 12345     <--- replace "12345" with the actual PID
```

thread apply all bt

I then got the output described at this github gist: https://gist.github.com/3448635

### ruby_gdb:

I used the ruby_gbd macros found on github  under pusewicz/ruby-gdb
then ran:

```
sudo gdb /path/to/ruby PID
```

In gdb: I attempted to run the following commands:

```
session-ruby
redirect_stdout # redirects gdb output to /tmp/ruby-debug.PID   
eval "caller"   # dumps backtrace
```

However when I attempted to redirect the process output to std_out, it appeared to kill the process, as I couldn't run eval 'caller' afterwards.

There was no output in /tmp/ruby-debug.12840 (the file didn't exist) However I did find this in the Apache error_log . This entry refers to the process that I attempted to debug  (PID = 12840)… However I'm not sure if this error refers to what the process was doing or the problem that was encountered when I attempted to redirect the std_out

The actual stack trace can be found at the gist here: https://gist.github.com/3448744

### SIGABRT

I have also tried killing the thread with a SIGABRT signal. Unfortunately nothing shows up in the log.

### Application versions:

Phusion Passenger 3.0.11,
Red hat linux
Ruby 1.9.3-p125
Rails 3.1.3

I would really appreciate any help with this. I have trawled through the mailing lists and forums trying to find answers to this but haven't had any success yet.
Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Both backtraces point to regex (onig-something is the regex engine of ruby) (=~ is regex matching), so it might be possible that one of the regexes applied isn't as finite as it should be - or simply processing a huge amount of data.